# Parsing JSON in Swift 5

Tags: json, swift, codable

I'm trying to parse a JSON file in Swift But I'm getting this error:

```
typeMismatch(Swift.Dictionary<Swift.String, Any>, Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [CodingKeys(stringValue: "OnDemandJSONURLs", intValue: nil), _JSONKey(stringValue: "English", intValue: nil)], debugDescription: "Expected to decode Dictionary<String, Any> but found a string/data instead.", underlyingError: nil))
```

Here is my code:

```
struct Entry: Codable {
    let OnDemandJSONURLs: [String: URLS]
}
struct URLS: Codable {
    let English: String
    let Korean: String
    let ChineseSimplified: String
    let German: String
    let Russian: String
    let Portuguese: String
    let Japanese: String
    let Spanish: String
    let ChineseTraditional:String
}

 func parseJSON() {
        if let url = URL(string: JSON_URLS) {
           URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url) { data, response, error in
           if let data = data {
               let jsonDecoder = JSONDecoder()
               do {
                   let parsedJSON = try jsonDecoder.decode(Entry.self, from: data)
                   print(parsedJSON)
               } catch {
                   print(error)
                   
               }
           }
           }.resume()
        }
    }
```

The JSON file is:

```
{
"OnDemandJSONURLs": {
        "English": "https://....json",
        "Korean": "https://....json",
        "ChineseSimplified":"https://....json",
        "German": "https://....json",
        "Russian": "https://....json",
        "Portuguese": "https://....json",
        "Japanese": "https://...json",
        "Spanish": "https://....json",
        "ChineseTraditional": "https://....json"
    }
}
```

What Am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You have to decode either `let OnDemandJSONURLs: [String: String]` (even `[String:URL]`) or `let OnDemandJSONURLs: URLS`

Comment: A little tip: You used on `JSONDecoder`: `Entry.self`, since you didn't override `init(from decoder:)` with more complex things, I'd suggest you do: `let entry = Entry(OnDemandJSONURLs: ["a": URLS(...), "b": URLS(...)]`, then encode it: `let encoded = try JSONEncoder().encode(entry)`, and see the output: `print(String(data: encoded, encoding: .utf8))`, and see the difference between the input and the output, it might help you understand what really is expecting the JSONDecoder to decode successfully your structs.

Comment: struct Entry: Codable {let OnDemandJSONURLs: URLS} worked just fine!